# How to add a docked item into another docked item?

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a panel which has a toolbar as docked item. I want to add a button inside this docked toolbar. But when i add it, it doesn't show up at all.
So how do I do that? Or is there a more convenient way to achieve this?

And, if I want to add it to the right side of the toolbar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example.  You use the "spacer" concept to float the button to the right side.  There is a good explanation of how this works [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?102989-docked-toolbar-and-button-positioning.-align-attribute-is-ignored.).

```
            new Ext.Application({
            launch: function() {
                var tapHandler = function (btn, evt) {
                    alert("Button '" + btn.text + "' tapped.");
                }
                var dockedItems = [
                    {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    title: 'Buttons',
                    ui: 'dark',
                    dock: 'top',
                    items: [
                        { xtype: 'spacer' },
                        { ui: 'forward', text: 'Forward' }
                    ],
                    defaults: { handler: tapHandler }
                }];
                new Ext.Panel({
                    fullscreen: true,
                    dockedItems: dockedItems,
                    html: 'Hello World!'
                });
            }
        });
```